# jQuery Ajaxstop inside of click event fired multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, woocommerce, click

On the woocommerce cart page I would like to add a notice if you use the quantity plus button and it is reaching the max stock. But I have an auto update on the cart, so I have to wait until the ajax load finishes to show the notice. What I realised using my script that the more you press the button after each ajax call the more times it is fired and the notice will be displayed more and more times. How to handle this? Thank you.

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '.plus.button.is-form', function(e) {
var inputval = jQuery(this).closest('div.quantity.buttons_added').find('input[name^="cart"]').val();
var inputmax = jQuery(this).closest('div.quantity.buttons_added').find('input[name^="cart"]').attr('max');
if(inputval==inputmax){
    jQuery( document ).ajaxStop( function($) {
        alert("TeSZT");
        jQuery('.woocommerce-notices-wrapper').html('<div class="woocommerce-info"><div class="woocommerce-info-text">Sajnos ebből a termékből jelenleg nincs több raktáron</div><span class="close-message"></span></div>');
    });

}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable to element to prevent multiple clicks. Enable this once `ajaxStop` is triggered for future use.

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '.plus.button.is-form', function(e) {
   
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.prop( "disabled", true );
   ...
   jQuery( document ).ajaxStop( function() {
       $this.prop( "disabled", false );     
   });
   ...
})
```